# C++ Google test Framework from shell script

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

We have a C++ application exe, which has some test cases and these test cases are written using Google Test framework and are running successfully.

But this exe handles all the Google test option internally (within
code) and because of this we are not able to generate the report for the Google test cases using Google test option (`--gtest_output=”xml: report.xml”`) through command prompt.

So our question is: if some exe handle the Google test within code and we want to get reports manually from the command prompt, then is there any option to do this?

And can we write a shell script to invoke Google test from the command prompt rather than executing the exe?

Comment: If the answer given isn't helping, then please clarify your question so that a better answer can be given.  You can comment on the answer even as a newcomer to the site when it is your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then your program runs the Google test code, but you do not (yet) have a mechanism to relay command line options related to Google test framework to your code that invokes the Google test framework.

If that's correct, then you'll need to add code to relay command line options for the test to your program.  You might add an option `--google-test="..."` where you then pass the argument value to the Google test infrastructure.  You'll have to worry about parsing multiple options out of one, etc.

You would then be able to invoke:

```
 your_program --google-test="-gtest_output=xml:report.xml" ...
```

and your code would manage that.  There is unlikely to be a standard way to handle that; nothing will automagically propagate command line arguments to the Google test framework.  (Note that your program would not see the quotes; they'd be removed by the shell.)

You could use an environment variable instead of a command line argument, but it is less desirable as an approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is using the recommended methods to invoke google test, it should be able by default to forward the --gtest_ command line options to the google test framework.

This is done by simply calling

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
```

If you want to abandon your exe, you could just link your compiled tests to the provide gtest_main lib, which provides a standard main program executing the tests.